# Problems with resolving dependency node-fetch from github - fork still necessary?

Tags: build-dependencies, node-fetch, archilogic, 3d.io

While trying to install build dependencies in a docker environment (no git), we got follwing error:

```
npm ERR! git clone --template=/home/node/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git@github.com:archilogic-com/node-fetch.git /home/node/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-archilogic-com-node-fetch-git-1-x-03653294: undefined
```

Problem seems the dependency `archilogic-com/node-fetch#1.x` [here](https://github.com/archilogic-com/3dio-js/blob/master/package.json#L28).

Ok. We should be able to handle this.

On the other hand, the question is wether the fork is still necessary.

Imho the reason for forking was [overriding the array-buffer](https://github.com/archilogic-com/node-fetch/commit/dfed82c36c95e97767c1ecfabf2d9714eb25d1db),
which is already done in [original node-fetch](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/blob/60cf26c2f3baf566c15632b723664b47f5b1f2db/src/body.js#L67).

Maybe i'm wrong but using the original would help us a lot.
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Indeed looks like an update would be a good idea!

A Pull request is welcome: https://github.com/archilogic-com/3dio-js

Thank you!

Comment: This has been resolved in 1.0.0-beta.32 if I am not mistaking? https://github.com/archilogic-com/3dio-js/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.32

Comment: Yes, beta.33 also fixes a glitch in beta.32